# Images in wp_mail not showing

Tags: email, wp-mail, html-email

I created a plugin that sends an email:

```
$subject = 'New comment - '.$post_title;
    ob_start();
    include(SUBSCRIBE_USER_BASE_DIR . '/email/message.php');
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    foreach($user_emails as $user_email){
        $to = $user_email;
        $send_mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
        if($send_mail){
            echo 'Mail sent';
        }else{
            $wpdb->print_error();
        }
    }
```

My email message is this:

```
<img src="<?php echo SUBSCRIBE_USER_BASE_DIR . '/email/email_header.png'; ?>" width="600px" height="100px" />
<div>A new comment has been posted on MySite.</div>
<div><?php echo get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>
<p><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></p>
</div>
```

Where SUBSCRIBE_USER_BASE_DIR is defined as:

```
define('SUBSCRIBE_USER_BASE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
```

This works fine except for the image not appearing. Instead it's an empty image placeholder.

I already define the email format prior in my plugin as follows:

```
function av_subscribe_format_email(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function('', 'return "text/html";' ) );
```

The format and image is also confirmed if I view the source of the resulting email:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><img src="/var/www/html/internal/wp-content/plugins/AV_-_Subscribe_User/email/email_header.png" width="600px" height="100px">
```

Yet the image still doesn't show.

**I should also mention that I allowed Downloading of images in Outlook to view the email.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I switched the image root path from

`define('SUBSCRIBE_USER_BASE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));`

to

`define('SUBSCRIBE_USER_BASE_URL',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));` and this worked.

`dirname(__FILE__)` registers:

```
<img src="/var/www/html/internal/wp-content/plugins/AV_-_Subscribe_User/email/email_header.png"
```

Whereas the latter `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)` outputs:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/AV_-_Subscribe_User/email/email_header.png"
```

I'm not 100% clear as to when to use which but I'm guessing that I would use dirname when I am operating within the site server.